# Type casts no longer work after ILRepack

Tags: c#, interface, f#, ilrepack

I am trying to create a single executable from the binaries of a project. This is what I have:

- A shared library dll, written in F#, I will refer to it by `A`
- A library dll, written in C# that implements a module interface (`IModule`) from `A`.  I will refer to this library as `B`
- An executable, written in F#, that at bootstrap time detects all available implementations of the `IModule` interface from `A` and instantiates the respective types - there is such implementation in `B`. I will refer to the executable as `C`

All projects target .NET 4.0; the F# projects use F# 3.0 (FSharp.Core 4.3.0.0), I am using Visual Studio 2017 Community.

All the logic is working fine when the files are not packed together (as if ran from the exe project's bin/Debug directory). When I produce the merged executable (using [ILRepack](https://github.com/gluck/il-repack) ), then the logic in the executable no longer detects which classes from `B` implement interfaces from `A`. In particular, I have the following check:

```
if (typedefof<IModule>.IsAssignableFrom(someType)) then ...
```

which is a code fragment from `A` that I use to detect `IModule` implemenations.  I suppose the ILRepack merging causes some type information to be lost in the process, preventing the above line from working.

A solution I used to get this work was to exclude the library `A` from the merged exe and just bring it along.

Is there a way to still have a single executable and get the type detection working? I'd prefer using a similar approach as the above interface detection, because once I find the desired types, I need them to be cast to `IModule` in order to further use them in my code.

My goal is to have the above 3 libraries bundled together in a single executable. However I'd also want to have other dll files, which implement `IModule` from `A` and be placed besides the executable. These dlls will be developed independently from `A`, `B` and `C` and their presence around the merged executable will vary depending on my use cases. I cant get them to work for the same reason.

Note, I also include the FSharp.Core dll in the packed executable for obvious reasons.

Comment: Is ILRepack doing pruning as well? Might be that those types are not used in any way other than through reflection, so it feels free to skip them when merging. Look into the merged binary in a disassembler and check if they're still there.

Comment: @scrwtp, not sure if it does, but the merged assembly size approximates the sum of the sizes of the source assemblies, thus I suppose it does not strip or optimize them. The interface type I am asking for is actively used within the merged assembly so I doubt it will get stripped